# force_ssl not working after adding in controller for specific methods in rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have added force_ssl option in  user controller

```
Class UserController < ApplicationController 
  force_ssl :only => [:login_form, :register]
end
```

I have both methods defined in Controller, my browsers are showing the errors as

In Chrome

```
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, 
or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error. An error occurred during a
```

In Firefox

```
connection to localhost:3000.
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

And server log is showing

```
!! Invalid request
```

Application is running in development environment but not with https but with http 
and in production its showing above errors

Comment: Got working myself, I generated self signed ssl certificate for development environment after this everything was perfect refereed http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule for configuration of ssl